# opencv python/Bounding boxes

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am trying to figure a solution to create a bounding box for all small objects that already have a rectangle around the contour and then crop the large bounding box. As the photo is attached, I need to find the red rectangle.

[image]

Comment: if every rectangle has coordinates `(x1,y1,x2,y2`) then you can use `min(all_x1)`, `min(all_y1)`,  `max(all_x2)`, `max(all_y2)` to get coordinates for this box. But I think `cv2` has special function for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think `opencv` may have function for this but I don't remeber name.

But even without `opencv` you can find it using `min()` `max()`
to get `min(all_x1)`, `min(all_y1)`, `max(all_x2)`, `max(all_y2)`

---

If you have rectangles `[x1,y1,x2,y2]`

```
rects = [
    [10, 20, 40, 30],
    [20, 10, 30, 40],
]

x1 = min(r[0] for r in rects)
y1 = min(r[1] for r in rects)
x2 = max(r[2] for r in rects)
y2 = max(r[3] for r in rects)

print(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

---

If you have rectangles `[x,y,width,height]`

```
rects = [
    [10, 20, 30, 10],
    [20, 10, 10, 30],
]

x1 = min(r[0] for r in rects)
y1 = min(r[1] for r in rects)
x2 = max(r[0]+r[2] for r in rects)
y2 = max(r[1]+r[3] for r in rects)

print(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```